# how can i customize yii checkbox html

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am new to yii and using yii `cgridview` to display the records . I want to use check-boxes to select the record .

what i want to produce the html like

```
<td>
    <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="check">
       <i class="input-new"></i>
     </label>
</td>
```

what i getting is

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</td>
```

code I am using is

```
array(
     'name' => 'check',
     'id' => 'selectedIds',
     'value' => '$data->rem_id',
     'class' => 'CheckBoxColumn',// <-- instead of CCheckBoxColumn
     'selectableRows' => '100',
     'headerTemplate'=>'<label class="checkbox">{item}<i class="input-new"></i></label>',
     'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array(
     'alt'=>'$data->rem_type','class'=>'check'),
 ),
```

Can some one help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to overwrite the `renderDataCellContent` function in your `CheckBoxColumn` class.

Like this:

```
<?php 
class CheckBoxColumn extends CCheckBoxColumn { 

    protected function renderDataCellContent($row,$data)
    {
        echo '<label class="checkbox">';
        echo $this->getDataCellContent($row);
        echo '<i class="input-new"></i>';
        echo '</label>';
    }
}
```

Good luck!